# Is CreateSQLQuery in HQL is Database independant

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

Could anyone help me to understand, CreateSQLQuery in HQL is Database independent

Please Find below example native SQL of SQLServer using CreateSQLQuery, in future if i need to migrate into Oracle will i need to do any code change required other than Connecting String to the DB.

Example of Native SQL SErver

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
   "select * from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode")
   .addEntity(Stock.class)
   .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native SQL queries created by createSQLQuery are database dependent. If you want to have a database independent code you should use [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) or [Criteria queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

Comment: All API's like CreateQuery,CreateCriteria in HQL are Database independant , not understanding why this CreateSQLQuery alone dependent on Database

Comment: CreateSQLQuery's purpose is to let you execute database-specific queries, that aren't supported by standard hibernate api.